# First Datepicker onchange 2nd date will automatic by 1 year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi friends is there any possible way to generate automate date by 1 year based on 1st datepicker..

```
$("#aggstarts").datepicker({
        nextText: "",
        prevText: "",
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: "true",
        yearRange: '1800:2030'       
        }
<input type="text" id="aggstart" class="datepicker form-control">
<input type="text" id="aggends">
```

Comment: yes ,What have you tried and make your question clear .

Comment: if i select 1st date , based on 1st date the 2nd date automatically generate by 1 year..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input-small " id="v_map_1"  date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input type="text" class="input-small " id="v_map_2"  date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
        $(function() {
            $( "#v_map_1" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "-d",
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                  var d=selectedDate.split("-");
                  var da=d[0];
                  var mo=d[1];
                  var yr=parseInt(d[2])+1;
                  var nd=da+"-"+mo+"-"+yr;
                  $( "#v_map_2" ).datepicker( "setDate", nd );
                 }
            });
            $( "#v_map_2" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
            });
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mGd8b/)

Comment: one more help sridhar if i select 08-06-2013 the auto generate date text box displays 31-05-2014.. how i achieve this..

Comment: clear your question if first box value 08-06-2013 means second box value should 31-05-2014 ?